# perl - formatting DateTime output

Tags: perl, datetime

How do I convert my return using DateTime from:

`This is my date:2011-11-26T20:11:06`
to
`This is my date:20111126`

Using this existing code:

```
use DateTime qw();
my $dt3 = DateTime->now->subtract(days => 1);
print "This is my date:$dt3\n"
```

Answer (score 12):

`ymd` is the simplest:

```
print "This is my date: ", $dt3->ymd(''), "\n";
```

`strftime` is more general purpose:

```
print "This is my date: ", $dt3->strftime('%Y%m%d'), "\n";
```

There are also specific (e.g. [DateTime::Format::Atom](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Atom)) and general (e.g. [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Strptime)) formatting helper tools you can use:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );
my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => '%Y%m%d' );
print "This is my date: ", $format->format_datetime($dt3), "\n";
```

PS — Your code will give the date in or near England, not the date where you are located. For that, you want

```
my $dt3 = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');
```

or the more appropriate

```
my $dt3 = DateTime->today(time_zone => 'local');
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add [`->ymd("")`](http://p3rl.org/DateTime#Get-Methods) on the second line. The parameter `""` is the separator, which you chose to be an empty string.

```
use DateTime qw();
my $dt3 = DateTime->now->subtract(days => 1)->ymd("");
print "This is my date:$dt3\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are about a dozen ways to process dates in Perl. However, if you know the format of the date string, there maybe no reason to call a datetime module:

```
$dt3 =~ /^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/;
print "This is my date:${1}${2}${3}\n";
```

I'm not familiar with DateTime, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't a way to format the data when you display it.

I personally prefer [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) and [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html) for these things. These modules have been part of the standard Perl installation since 5.10. Plus, I find the interface to be fairly simple and clean.

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $time = localtime;
$time -= ONE_DAY;

print "This is my date:" . $time->ymd("");
```

For some reason, you can't say `$time = localtime - ONE_DAY;` on the same line. I guess you need to create the `Time::Piece` object first before you can manipulating them with the `Time::Second` constants.