# Printing year, month and date from DateTime in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I am pretty new to Perl and I need to extract the month, day and time from the DateTime object in Perl.

The following code is what I currently have:

```
use strict;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", time_zone => 'UTC',
    on_error  => 'croak');
my $date1 = $parser->parse_datetime("2017-10-10T04:21:56Z");
print STDERR "Year: $date1->year()";
```

I always get my output as this:
Year: 2017-10-10T04:21:56->year().

What am I doing wrong? Or should I be printing the year outside double quotes?

Comment: _Or should I be printing the year outside double quotes?_ Yes. The DateTime object is stringifying when you interpolate it inside double quotes, which is why you're seeing the ISO 8601 representation of your date. Methods need to be invoked outside of strings.

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288688/perl-formatting-datetime-output) by @ikegami

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that method calls (or, indeed, any subroutine calls) are not expanded in a quoted string. You need to use concatenation here:

```
print STDERR "Year: " . $date1->year();
```

Or pass multiple arguments to `print()`:

```
print STDERR "Year: ", $date1->year();
```

Also note that `print STDERR` is usually spelled `warn(...)`.

**Update:** It's also worth pointing out what is actually happening here. When Perl sees `$date1->year()` in your quoted string, it recognises `$date1` as a variable and wants to expand that to its value. The value of a blessed reference is usually something like "Class=HASH(0x012345679ABCDEF)" (where "Class" is the class name). But DateTime overrides stringification to present a string version of the date and time.

Comment: This is a good answer. Another version (a worse version though) of this answer is, that if you want to embed code in a double quoted string, you have to use the black magic operator `@{[ ]}` to construct a temporary array reference and immediately dereference it, like so: `warn "Year: @{[ $date1->year() ]}";`

Comment: @Bass: I deliberately omitted the baby-cart operator from my answer. It's probably a little scary for a Perl beginner. And besides, I'd never use it in a case like this.

Comment: @DaveCross: I wasn't aware of the interpolation perl tries to do when there are method calls inside double quotes. Thank you for this answer. This helps greatly!